# Probability Uniform Distribution 4

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that X has a uniform distribution on the interval $(0, a)$, where $a > 0$.
Find $\text{Pr}(X > X^2)$.

I feel that if $a\le1$ then the above probability will be 1(not sure though). But what if value of $a>1$ then how to solve. Please show the notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\leq 1$, the probability is 1.

if $a >1$, $X < X^2$ iff $X<1$, which gives us $\frac{1}{a}$

Conclusion:

$Pr(X>X^2)=Pr(X<1)=\frac{1}{\max(a,1)}$